# Is it safe to connect and remove a PlayStation controller while the PC is turned on?

Tags: usb

Is it completely safe to remove or insert a PlayStation controller USB connection while the PC is on?

[image]

Is there any harm in it?

Comment: The only issue might be where you've got a file open for edit, and you pull the stick out in which case you'll lose the changes.

Comment: Its a controller that I am speaking about

Comment: I didn't click the link, as I'm unaware of its legitimacy. In the case of a controller, then sure there's no issue unplugging a USB device.

Comment: OP, please edit your original question to make it more clear what you're asking.  The title should be "Is it safe to remove a Playstation controller from a PC while the PC is turned on?".  The question should have good grammar and spacing, and the link should be at the end.

Comment: Links might be malicious, and links will break over time, so it's best to get all of the important information in the text of the question.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine.  USB devices are designed to unplug and replug with little danger, such as when someone trips over a cable.

If you have an external hard drive or thumb drive, then those should be Ejected from the OS before unplugging.  In 2018 with Windows 10, it's not as important to Eject as it was 10 years ago, but it's still a good idea.

Comment: Beat me to it... :)

Comment: `In 2018 with Windows 10, it's not as important to Eject as it was 10 years ago` , unless you have write cache enabled for usb devices, in which case it is very important to first eject the usb drive as the cache may still be used to write to the usb drive.